# Jquery animation hangs when user scrolls up and down too fast

Tags: jquery

So I have this code that makes a div box shorter or longer, depending on the scroll position. The thing is, if the user scrolls down then scrolls up really quickly, it makes it shorter, then hangs for about a second before it makes the div longer again.
Why is this?

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 60) {
        $("ul.undermenu").animate({width:'100px'}, 500);;
     }
     else {
         $("ul.undermenu").animate({width:'1000px'}, 500);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing this event at rapid speeds when you scroll. Hence you should clear the animation queue with `.stop(true, false)`

```
var win = $(window),
    menu = $("ul.undermenu"),
    css = { width: 1000 };        

win.bind('scroll', function() {
    css.width = win.scrollTop() > 60 ? 100 : 1000;
    menu.stop(true, false).animate(css, 500);
});
```

The `stop` function takes 2 booleans as parameters:

- clear the animation queue
- jump to end in the animation

For you to decide which combination works smooth enough.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/w8dss12y/)**

**[jQuery stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)**

Comment: I guessed as much! I tried adding that and it stopped it all working though. Or did I add it wrong? can you show me how I'd use it properly?

Comment: apparently `.stop(true, false)` seems to work better. see fiddle