# Strange Jquery animation bug in Firefox hanging before running

Tags: jquery

I have a really simple Jquery animation that doesn't seem to wrok in Firefox very well. It takes a really long time to start running because it's doing some weird thing in the background. Here's a video of what's happening. Take note of the highlighted line in the code viewer (also Firefox was being really laggy as usual, however that isn't the cause of the problem):
http://byonex.co.uk/ffbug.mp4

And here's the script I'm using:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 60) {
        $("ul.undermenu").animate({width:'100px'}, { duration: 500});
        $("ul.undermenu").animate({height:'60px'}, { duration: 200});
     }
     else {
         $("ul.undermenu").animate({height:'30px'}, { duration: 200});
         $("ul.undermenu").animate({width:'1000%'}, { duration: 500});
     }
});
```

Anyone have a clue what's going on here?

Comment: Maybe if you just made it accessible, it'd be better. I didn't really get what is wrong / what you want from the video.

Comment: Suggestion: Use CSS transitions and `addClass`/`removeClass` instead of `animate`.

Comment: What's happening is Firefox takes ages to run the script when I scroll. Also, Alexander, good suggestion. I may try it, although I kind of want to use Jquery so I can change a few parameters that aren't CSSable

Comment: Just been testing in other browsers now. Maybe FF is just having a bug day/my version is just broken. I'll try on another PC when I have access

Comment: Should I add my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870193/jquery-animation-hangs-when-user-scrolls-up-and-down-too-fast/27870286#27870286) again or what's the point here? ^^ I don't see a fresh page reload in the video you provided ...

Comment: Ah, Tim! Basically, I was trying to mess around with the code and add a few more parts to it before I added the .stop (which I've now done, thanks for your answer), but the problem is, when I scroll, the Jquery script is supposed to make the box shrink in width and grow in height, then when I scroll back up, it shrinks in height, before getting wider. It works fine and dandy in all browsers, except now, in Firefox, it seems to hang after scrolling down for a good few seconds and then the box does its business. It appears to be some sort of bug, rather than a code error I'm thinking now